# onListItemClick is not work for added two clickable items in the list row

Tags: java, android

I created a ListFragment by using a custom adapter. OnListItemClick is not work after I add a button in the list row. If I click on the list row it should be intent to other class, but now when I click on the list row, it did not have any action. No error and no action. So I think it might because there has two clickable items in the list row, so the onListItemClick is not work. But I do not know how can I solve this problem.

**Fragment1.java**

```
public class Fragment1 extends ListFragment implements AdapterInterface{

    public Fragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show_queue, container, false);

        // initialize the items list
        mItems = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();

        // initialize and set the list adapter
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter2(getActivity(), mItems, this);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void buttonPressed(int position) {
        System.out.println("Fragment1: " + position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), QueueDetail.class);
        i.putExtra("qid", qid.get(position).toString());
        startActivity (i);
    }

}
```

**ListViewAdapter2.java**

```
public class ListViewAdapter2 extends ArrayAdapter<ListViewItem> {
    AdapterInterface buttonListener;
    private int position;

    public ListViewAdapter2(Context context, List<ListViewItem> items, AdapterInterface buttonListener) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_layout2, items);
        this.buttonListener = buttonListener;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        this.position = position;

        if(convertView == null) {
            // inflate the GridView item layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout2, parent, false);

            // initialize the view holder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            viewHolder.txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
            viewHolder.smallTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.smallTxt);
            viewHolder.datetime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.datetime);
            viewHolder.viewBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewBtn);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            // recycle the already inflated view
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.viewBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("ListViewAdapter: " + position);
                buttonListener.buttonPressed(position);
            }
        });

        ...

        return convertView;
    }

    private int getViewBtnPosition(){
        return position;
    }
}
```

**fragment_show_queue.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

**listview_layout2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/datetime"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/datetime">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/smallTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/datetime"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/viewBtn"
        android:text="JOIN"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:background="#b5e61d"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `OnListItemClick is not work`.  A "shrug" report.  What does "not work" mean?

Comment: It means when I click on the list item, there are no any action to intent to other class, like a button if you set enable to false, and click on it, it will no have any action.

Comment: so this method is not called `viewHolder.viewBtn.setOnClickListener` ?

Comment: No, OnListItemClick called when the list row clicked. viewHolder.viewBtn.setOnClickListener called when the button that is in the list row. I added the xml file for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` to your `Button` in the row's layout file.